# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I don't know what I am doing wrong in the last line

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function() { 
            var currentHeight = 1;
            currentHeight = $('.footer').outerHeight();
            console.log(currentHeight);
            var newPadbod = parseInt(currentHeight)+"px";
            console.log(newPadbod);
            $("body").css("padding-bottom" , newPadbod);
       });
</script>
```

Comment: can you give us more informations ? what does your console.log looks like ? what is your html structure ?

Comment: `jQuery('.footer')` ---> we use $ OR jQuery, never both at the same time ... so try `$('footer')` or `jQuery('body')`

Comment: What issue are you facing ?

Comment: console shows only this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: the last line is fine, you must've mispelled a dom name

Comment: @TemaniAfif i tried that but no working

Comment: its working if I don't terminate the command 
$("body").css("padding-bottom" , newPad)
but I want to know why it's work now

Comment: am pretty sure you have more code after this, can you show us the full page ?

Comment: Do you get the line number in the exception?

Comment: yeah in line  $("body").css("padding-bottom" , newPadbod);